# AWK syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

I am making a script as a sudo user that sends me CPU usage for my server, and mails me with the result of another script,

```
sudo sh -c '{
x=`ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f 3,11- |awk '\'BEGIN { OFS = " " } { $1 = $1"%"; print }'\'`
/opt/fetch_script.sh $x
}| mailx mymail@mymail.com'
```

But it still gives me error cause of the AWK usage:

```
awk: 0: unexpected character '\'
aux: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any help please?

Comment: It's probably your nested quotes. What exactly are you trying to do? You should be able to get specific ps fields without all that extra processing e.g. `ps axo pcpu= o comm=` or `ps -e -o pcpu= o comm=`

Comment: I am building up script, that should print out the top 5 process that consumes the cpu, that printing the "cpu and process_name" columns only, to be like "5%   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start", thats the output that i wish for.

Comment: The script should be run for remote servers, so i run it under as sudo user,

Comment: You could try something like `sh -c '/opt/fetch_script.sh "$(ps axo pcpu= o comm= | awk '\''{$1=$1"%"; print}'\'')"'`

Comment: Worked like a charm :), thanks alot, please post your answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely your attempt to nest quotes, however you are over-complicating things by not making use of the `ps` command's output format options. A simpler version (with consistent quoting) might be

```
sh -c '/opt/fetch_script.sh "$(ps axo pcpu= o comm= | awk '\''{$1=$1"%"; print}'\'')"'
```